# Android connot open database file error

Tags: android, sqlite, local-database

Refering [this](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-database-tutorial.html) tutorial I am developing an android application with a SQLLite database

But getting the following error

```
(14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
(14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(//data/data/com.testdata/databases/database.db) - 
Failed to open database 'data/data/com.testdata/databases/database.db'.
```

As described in that tutorial I just kept my database file named "db" ( not having any extension ) in to my "assets" folder

**And my Code looks like**

```
    package com.testdata.data;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class DataBaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // The Android's default system path of your application database.
    //data/data/ and /databases remain the same always. The one that must be changed is com.example which represents
    //the MAIN package of your project
    private static String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.testdata/databases/";

    //the name of your database
    private static String DB_NAME = "database.db";

    private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

    private static DataBaseManager sInstance = null;
    // database version    
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     */
    private DataBaseManager() {
        super(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(), DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        try {
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Singleton for DataBase
     *
     * @return singleton instance
     */
    public static DataBaseManager instance() {

        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DataBaseManager();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }


    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     *
     * @throws java.io.IOException io exception
     */
    private void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method an empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database doesn't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     *
     * @throws java.io.IOException io exception
     */
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    private void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    /**
     * Select method
     *
     * @param query select query
     * @return - Cursor with the results
     * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
     */
    public Cursor select(String query) throws SQLException {
        return mDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

    /**
     * Insert method
     *
     * @param table  - name of the table
     * @param values values to insert
     * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
     */
    public void insert(String table, ContentValues values) throws SQLException {
        mDataBase.insert(table, null, values);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param table - table name
     * @param where WHERE clause, if pass null, all the rows will be deleted
     * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
     */
    public void delete(String table, String where) throws SQLException {

        mDataBase.delete(table, where, null);

    }

    /**
     * Update method
     *
     * @param table  - table name
     * @param values - values to update
     * @param where  - WHERE clause, if pass null, all rows will be updated
     */
    public void update(String table, ContentValues values, String where) {

        mDataBase.update(table, values, where, null);

    }

    /**
     * Let you make a raw query
     *
     * @param command - the sql comand you want to run
     */
    public void sqlCommand(String command) {
        mDataBase.execSQL(command);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Can anyone please help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your full DatabaseMAnager class..

Comment: hi thanks code updated

Comment: You create database in the abstract method i.e Oncreate() and onupdate()..

Comment: thanks for the reply .. can you became little more clear ? I am new to android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating your `Database file` in the `sqlite browser`. Copy the created db file in the `assets` folder. Then reopen the `db file` in the assets folder that has been copied in the sqlite browser. Make sure the database file is not corrupted. If it is fine and every data is as perfect as you inserted previously, then there should be no issues.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to have your DB distributed with your application? Then use this package to do the job:

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
private static String DB_NAME = "database.db";
```

to

```
private static String DB_NAME = "database";
```

Comment: changed .. but no luck .. any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

to go upto the database directory,use following piece of code,

inside constructor of `DataBaseManager`

```
try {
        DB_PATH = mContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir +"/databases/";    //mContext is the context of class which had instantiated the DataBaseManager class to deal with database operations
        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, is that createDatabase(); is needed ? because we already created the database is it ?  because I am getting this error :- android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: employee (code 1)

Comment: Yes,it is needed.kindly post your logcat